# A dirty hoe brought me woe

Tags: riddle

Such a puzzle verse with a bit of a *word play*:

> A dirty hoe brought me woe,
>   But I'll be digging more

Who is it about?

Answer (score 2):

You are

> a weed?

*A dirty hoe brought me woe,*

> Dug up and destroyed by a hoe ...

*But I'll be digging more*

> ... but still undefeated and has roots to continue spreading.

Comment: A good version, but let's wait for more answers.

Comment: Does a good version imply it is the correct answer, or a good attempt but not it? You don't want to 'wait for more answers' if it's a riddle with a unique solution and it's been found. Otherwise it can be closed as too broad.

Comment: @n_palum I mean the latter, that is a good attempt but, unfortunately, not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer although this seems broad with no line to make a unique solution.

You are:

> A Miner (Since you said *Who* is it about)

*A dirty hoe brought me woe*

> They used a backhoe to dig for gold or other minerals but were disappointed in not finding anything.

*But I'll be digging more*

> They will continue to dig and are not discouraged.